# Volley CacheDispatcher hangs

Tags: android, android-volley

I've created my own request and in the constructor I set `setShouldCache(Boolean.TRUE);` .

When the request is called for the first time (no cache is used) then all is good and I can see the content being cached. Second time I call the same URL a bizarre thing happens:

```
else {
                // Insert 'null' queue for this cacheKey, indicating there is now a request in
                // flight.
                mWaitingRequests.put(cacheKey, null);
                mCacheQueue.add(request); <-- being called
```

Extracted from `RequestQueue.add`.

I can see in the debugger that `mCacheQueue`fills up, but nothing is being called from it, .e.g

```
// Take a request from the queue.
request = mCacheQueue.take();
```

Extracted from `CacheDispatcher.run`.

is stuck.

This is the piece of code that creates the request:

```
  RequestFuture<String> future = _requestFutureProvider.get();
  FetchArticleImageRequest request = new FetchArticleImageRequest(pageId,
                            300,
                            future, future);
 _requestQueue.add(request);
 try {
         // this will never block
         imgUrl = future.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 } catch (Exception e) {
         log.error("Unable to fetch img url", e);
 }
```

One more piece of information, I'm running the request inside `parseQueryResponse` of another request, so it does not run in the main thread.

BTW when not using cache all is working well (e.g. requests are being made against the server).

Any idea what is going here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Tx to our buddies in google groups (Ficus Kirkpatrick) there is an answer.

It happened because I ran a Future request inside another request which ran as part of the cache dispatcher. My solution was to remove caching from the request that dispatched the other requests.